# How to quickly find common values ​in a list of (sorted?) lists?

Tags: python, numpy, performance, optimization

### EDIT:

Originally posted with the question below,
but since a practical walkaround was found I changed the title to match the walkaround.
See the bottom of the details.

## Question (OLD)

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47957961/how-to-create-a-boolean-array-from-an-array-of-indices-in-numpy) (which already solved), I want to create a boolean array from an array of indices, but I need a much faster solution.

[The code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47958796/18125313) in the above answer takes up to 80% of my code's execution time. So I want to speed it up somehow.

## Details

In case you are wondering, here are the details of what I want to do.

I have a table that has about 50 columns and over 2 million rows.
All elements are uint8 in the range of 0 to 200.

```py
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
table = np.random.randint(0, 201, (10, 5), dtype=np.uint8)  # rows=10, cols=5
```

The table looks like this:

```py
array([[172,  10, 127, 140,  47],
       [170, 196, 151, 117, 166],
       [ 22, 183, 192,  33,  67],
       [179,  78, 154,  82, 162],
       [195, 118, 125, 139, 103],
       [125,   9, 164, 116, 108],
       [161, 159,  21,  81,  89],
       [165, 102,  98,  36, 183],
       [  5, 112,  87,  58,  43],
       [ 76,  70,  60,  75, 189]], dtype=uint8)
```

For each column, an accepted row indices is given by user as follows:

```py
accepted_rows_for_column_0 = [1, 2, 5, 6]
accepted_rows_for_column_1 = [0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9]
accepted_rows_for_column_2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]
accepted_rows_for_column_3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8]
accepted_rows_for_column_4 = [2, 3, 6, 9]

# for convenient
accepted_rows = [accepted_rows_for_column_0, accepted_rows_for_column_1,
                 accepted_rows_for_column_2, accepted_rows_for_column_3,
                 accepted_rows_for_column_4]

# also, all unaccepted row indices are accessible
unaccepted_rows = ...
```

Here is some code to generate an actual size table for testing (if you want to try it out).

```py
import numpy as np
import random

np.random.seed(0)
random.seed(0)

table = np.random.randint(0, 201, (2 * 10 ** 6, 50), dtype=np.uint8)
accepted_rows = [
    np.array(sorted(random.sample(list(range(table.shape[0])), random.randint(table.shape[0] // 2, table.shape[0]))))
    for _ in range(table.shape[1])
]
```

Now, I want to extract all rows where all columns are accepted.
In the example above (10x5 table), 2 and 6 are the target row indices.

```py
expected_result = table[[2, 6]]
```

```py
array([[ 22, 183, 192,  33,  67],
       [161, 159,  21,  81,  89]], dtype=uint8)
```

The following is a solution using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47958796/18125313).

```py
def as_boolean_array(indices, size):
    t = np.zeros(size, dtype=bool)
    t[np.array(indices)] = True  # This line is slow.
    return t

indices = np.array([as_boolean_array(idx, len(table)) for idx in accepted_rows]).all(axis=0)

results = table[indices]
```

This is the fastest way I have found.
The execution time is about 350 msec even for a table with 2 million rows.
However, more than 300 msec of that time is spent on a single line that is doing fancy indexing.

As for the execution environment,
table is in memory, and there is about 2GB of free memory and 10GB of SSD disk.
Since the program itself runs in multiple processes,
parallelization using multiprocessing is ineffective.

Any suggestions?

### EDIT:

As @myrtlecat and @Michael Szczesny mentioned in the comments section, if the indices are sorted, the intersection can be computed relatively fast.
By merging them first, I was able to greatly reduce the number of slow fancy indexing runs.

```py
import sortednp as snp
indices = as_boolean_array(snp.kway_intersect(*accepted_rows), len(table))
results = table[indices]
```

Note: The execution time of `kway_intersect` seems to depend on the number of accepted indices. It it actually slower when most of the indices are accepted. In my case, I can easily get around this problem by using an unaccepted indices instead.

Comment: In your first example the accepted rows are given sorted, but in your test code they are not. Can we assume that they are sorted? Finding the common elements of sorted arrays can be made very fast (see e.g. the `sortednp` package, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51269977/8742505))

Comment: @myrtlecat Thank you for the comment. The test code is wrong, the indices are given sorted, I've tried `sortednp` and it seems to be several times faster in most cases (also I've edited my post). Could you post your comment as an answer so that I can mark it as best answer?